# Create tar-file without folder strucure

Tags: compression, tar, directory-structure

I have to compress multiple files to one tar-File. As I have to repeat this for many files in many different folders I wrote a shell script and started it from a parent directory. The shell script contains multiple lines like the following:

```
tar -cf a/b/c/tarfile.tar a/b/c/*
```

This creates a tar-file in the specified folder but inside the tar-File the folder structure of a/b/c/ is still existent.

What I want is that all files in c/ are placed in tarfile.tar WITHOUT the folder structure a/b/c/. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`tar -cf a/b/c/tarfile.tar -C a/b/c .` will switch to the directory `a/b/c` and read in the entire directory (the `.` - you could specify specific files as well, but a wildcard will not do what you're expecting). The `-C <directory> <filelist>` pattern can be repeated as necessary to process additional files from different locations.

Another possibility given your original example would be `cd a/b/c; tar cf ../../../tarfile.tar *`, but that doesn't give you the possibility to pull multiple files from different locations (of course you could still use `-C`, but the relative paths would have to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: thanks twalberg, I tried your 2nd advice and it worked. (cd into direcotry first and then create tar-File)